# Fitting a logarithmic trendline on already logged values

Tags: regression, logistic, variance, data-visualization, logarithm

This is the situation. I am running trials with a population simulator, which produces various outputs (y), with the variance of these outputs being dependent on the number of clones (x) (recursions) the simulator has gone through.

```
Clone Number (x) Population (y) Natural Log (ln y)
0                36181481.58    17.40405799
1                36183152.15    17.40410416
2                36184827.55    17.40415046
3                36184190.42    17.40413285
4                36184894.51    17.40415231
5                36183738.46    17.40412036
6                36183528.37    17.40411456
7                36183558.40    17.40411539
8                36183393.78    17.40411084
9                36183755.57    17.40412084
10               36184415.17    17.40413906
15               36182566.54    17.40408797
20               36183791.79    17.40412184
```

Generally speaking, the higher the cloning; the lower the variance. My task is to prove this relationship. So far I've done several tests to prove this such as %change of y between each x, and distance from y-mean for each x, etc. and would like to do an additional test using the ln differences (which from my understanding also represents the %change for a given dataset).

---

**MY QUESTION IS: On Excel, would plotting the ln of y against x, then adding the "Logarithmic Trendline" option make sense?** The log trendline seems to fit my data the best (for obvious reasons), and I was planning to take the *distance from each (x,**y**) to the trendline equation* to have percentages showing by how much each additional recursion of x differs. But I'm wondering if this makes mathematical sense. I know that plotting the ln of y with x with a *linear trendline* makes sense, similar in the way that plotting non-logged y with x with a *logarithmic trendline* would make sense, but I'm kind of stumped as to justifying why using a logarithmic trendline on already-logged values of y makes sense (even though it makes for the best graph).

Should I continue with my idea or should I be content with simply plotting ln y with x with a linear trendline to show this relationship?

## 1. This is what I have and what makes mathematical sense to me

[image: #1. This is what I have and what makes mathematical sense to me]

## 2. This is what I want to use (but not sure if it makes sense)

[image: #2. This is what I want to use (but not sure if it makes sense)]

***essentially, I am wondering if option #2 would result in mathematically-useful value for analysis, or would I just be analyzing mathematical nonsense? I guess another way to look at this question is - is there value in using a trendline equation as the comparison/reference, and is it appropriate to use a logarithmic trendline for ln values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel is pretty limited in what it offers as an analysis package. Of the two graphs, I agree the #2 using double-logged response looks a better fit (the r^2 would easily verify). But the best choice of trendline depends on the question you are trying to answer. There is no mathematical reason to reject double-logging the outcome, only contextual reasons.

One mathematical challenge of this double-logged approach is that you constrain the response to run through the origin at $X=0$. Now, this is probably not appropriate. We could speak more intelligently on this if you followed the golden rule of statistics: label your axes.

In my experience, these kinds of "taper" peak curves are best fit with non-linear least squares. I am not sure if Excel offers a way to do this, but R does.

A functional model of the form:

$$ E[Y|X] = \alpha + \frac{\beta X}{X + \delta}$$

Takes value $\alpha$ when $X=0$ and instantaneously rises at a rate of $\beta/\delta$ but tapers off achieves a peak value of $\alpha + \beta$ as $X \rightarrow \infty$.

This is a pragmatic way of fitting curves, and connection the estimates to interpretable values.

Comment: Hey Adam, thank you for your helpful response. I am glad there is no mathematical reason to reject the use of #2, and you would be correct in it having a higher R^2. I guess with #1 I was trying to prove the "taper" through a mathematical context (in that using ln y values with a linear fit proves the relationship is non-linear).... however, the difference between ln y values also mathematically portrays the %change and I guess I got a bit lost contextually when I decided to take the difference between these ln y values to the trendline equation.

Comment: Also, sorry about the axes, I edited in the proper ones now. As for your suggestion, I will look into using non-linear least squares as I am thankfully familiar with R. Since this is for work, and my workplace is not heavily mathematically-inclined, I think using #2 should be fine. If they question why I used a logarithmic trendline I think it will suffice to say that it was the one that fitted the data the best, correct?